# Dropping the "positive" and "decreasing" conditions in the integral test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

I know the **Integral test** is the following theorem:

> Assume $f$ is continuous, **positive**, and **decreasing** on [$1, \infty$).
>
> If $\int_1 ^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exists and is finite, then $\sum f(n)$ converges and vice versa.

I am searching for counterexamples to this test if:

(i)
the condition **positive** is dropped;

(ii) the condition **decreasing** is dropped.

Comment: My first thought is that counterexamples, while extant, may be a bit too pathological to define explicitly (I'm sure, however, that some clever analysis folks can find something). To me, it is more important to understand that these are sufficient conditions for $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ to serve as a lower bound for $\sum_1^\infty s_n$ and as an upper bound for $\sum_2^\infty s_n$. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx

Comment: If it is negative and decreasing, it can't even pass the test for divergence, right?

Answer (score 6):

$\sin^2(\pi n)$ converges as a summation, but not as an integral.

Edit:  As Nico points out, you can make this strictly positive by adding $1/n^2$.

Comment: Which point is this addressing? If you are dropping the hypothesis of decreasing while keeping positivity, this doesn't work, while if you are trying to drop positivity while keeping decreasing, this also doesn't work. This function is zero at certain points, hence not positive there.

Comment: I think you may be able to salvage it by adding $\frac{1}{n^2}$ to your example.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above, negative and decreasing is trivial.  This is meant to address why you cannot relax the decreasing condition.

Answer (score 4):

When you drop the "decreasing" condition, both directions fail even with the "positive" condition!
$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}
$

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \l( \sin(nπ)^2 + \lfrac1{n^2} \r) = \color{blue}{\lfrac{π^2}{6}}$ **but** $\int_1^\infty \l( \sin(nπ)^2 + \lfrac1{n^2} \r)\ dn = \color{red}{\infty}$.
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lfrac1{n^4 \sin(nπ)^2+1} = \color{red}{\infty}$ **but** $\int_1^\infty \lfrac1{n^4 \sin(nπ)^2+1}\ dn < \color{blue}{\lfrac{π^2}{6}}$.

To derive the above inequality, note the following for any $k \in \nn_+$ and $n \in [k,k+1]$:

- $\int_k^{k+1} \lfrac1{n^4 \sin(nπ)^2+1}\ dn < \int_k^{k+1} \lfrac1{(k^4-1) \sin(nπ)^2+1}\ dn = \int_{-\frac12}^\frac12 \lfrac1{(k^4-1) \sin(xπ)^2+1}\ dx = \lfrac1{k^2}$.

  [To get the last integral, use the substitution $t = \tan(xπ)$.]

Comment: In your integration how the limits of integration comes from $\displaystyle \int_k^{k+1}$ to $\displaystyle \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: @S717717: Because $\sin(xπ)^2 = \frac12( 1 - \cos(2πx) )$ has period $1$ in $x$.

Comment: User21820)) Ok. But I got the final answer of the integral is $\pi^2 /k^2$ instead of $1/k^2$.

Comment: @S717717: Um numerical integration agrees with me. Did you forget some factor somewhere? Letting $t = \tan(xπ)$ we get $\sin(xπ)^2 = \lfrac{t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\lfrac{dt}{dx} = π \sec(xπ)^2 = π(1+t^2)$ and hence $\int \lfrac1{(k^4-1) \sin(xπ)^2 + 1} = \int \lfrac{1+t^2}{(k^4-1) t^2 + (1+t^2)}\ dx = \int \lfrac{1}{π(k^4 t^2 + 1)}\ dt = \cdots$.

Comment: Okk..I got it..Sorry for my mistake..!

Comment: @S717717: No problem. Other people may have the same inquiry or wish to see the integral evaluation as well. =)

Comment: One more question please..By which test the series is divergent ?

Comment: I just got it..As $\sin^2(n.\pi)=0$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ so it is trivial..! Thanks for providing a very nice example.

Comment: @S717717: Yup! You're welcome! I went to find these examples partly out of curiosity as to how nice examples I could find. =)

Answer (score 1):

There can't be a convergent series or integral that's negative and decreasing, since it would by definition be above a given absolute value for sufficiently large n or t.  So for negative, decreasing, and continuous, it's trivially true.

For decreasing, there's no reason you can't have a continuous (albeit not differentiable) function like a saw, with lines running to $\frac{1}{x^2}$ at integers, and 2 at the halfway points between integers.  That would be a counterexample, since the integral between any two positive integers would never drop below 1, so the integral wouldn't converge, even though the series would.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence $(f(n))_n$ such that $\sum_1^\infty f(n)$ converges, you can extend $f$ to  a continuous real function that does just about anything you want on each $[n,n+1].$

For example for each $n,$ let $f(x)$ be linear on $[n,n+1/2]$ and linear on $[n+1/2, n]$ with $f(n+1/2)$ large enough  that $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\;dx>1.$ Then $\int_1^{\infty}f(x)\;dx=\infty.$ Of course $f$ is not monotonic.