# Understanding Integral test

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Why, for applying the integral test, the function should be positive and decreasing on the concerned interval? If the function was positive and increasing, the integral test would indicate divergence which would actually be the case. So why is the condition positive and decreasing necessary?

Comment: This isn't quite right. You want to look at the picture — in your case, with circumscribed rectangles — and you'll deduce that $$\sum_{n=a}^b \frac 1n > \int_a^{b+1}\frac{dx}x.$$

Comment: Nevermind I got it.  Please look at the second question though

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033801/dropping-the-positive-and-decreasing-conditions-in-the-integral-test

Comment: Because in the case of a positive increasing function divergence is obvious.

Comment: @zhw. That's what i am stating. If the decreasing condition is removed the integral test still works. I understand as in the link given above that there are counterexamples but can somebody explain the problem that occur intuitively. (I am a pre-university student so the math language used at the link above went over my head).

Comment: Please do not erase the original question and replace it with a completely different one. That is inconsiderate and bad form here. Feel free to edit or add details, but not what you've done!

Comment: Generally, if the summand were positive and increasing, you should've used the $n$th term test already, so there's really no point for the integral test by then.  Only a matter of uselessness.